# Create video from sequence images stored in one folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, video-processing, video-capture

I want to create mp4 video from images stored in a folder. I already rename all images like (1.jpg,2.jpg,...1000.jpg).
I want to create video with every 5 images (1-5,6-10,11-15,...,995-1000) to video with 5 fps and save video.

Input:- 1000 images.
Output:- 200 videos with 5fps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate every 5 images in a array and create the video accordingly

```
for i in range(1,20): #can base on number of image in your directory
    if(i+4 > 20):
        break
    print(str(i)+" "+str(i+4)) # use this to append your image into array
    img_array = []
    for j in range(i, i+5):
        filename = str(j)+".jpg"
        img = cv2.imread(filename)
        height, width, layers = img.shape
        size = (width,height)
        img_array.append(img)

    #Create Video
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_file,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V'), fps, size)
    for i in range(len(img_array)):
        out.write(img_array[i])
    out.release()

    i = i+4
```